# How to search Global Catalog and return a list of UserPrincipals?

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal

I use the following code to search Global Catalog:

```
public SearchResultCollection SearchGlobalCatalog(string username)
{
    var de = new DirectoryEntry("GC://SERVERNAME", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
    var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
    ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + username + "*))";
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;                
    var searchResults = ds.FindAll();

    return searchResults;
}
```

Now, the problem is I don't know how to get a list of `UserPrincipal` objects from `SearchResultCollection`. The reason I want to do that is to get access to some user properties that are not available in Global Catalog, like Employee ID.

Comment: Why is Employee ID not available? Where is it stored?

Comment: Because not all attributes are replicated to the Global Catalog. I can get the Employee ID by searching the Active Directory using a PrincipalContext with the ContextType of Domain. But, I don't know how to get access to those additional attributes by searching the Global Catalog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UserPrincipal` is a part of the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

Use the helper classes in that namespace to get `UserPrincipal` objects.

Without using a `UserPrincipal` try something like this:

```
using (var userBinding = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.forest.company.com"))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(userBinding))
    {
        adSearch.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
        adSearch.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + username + "*))";
        adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeID");
        adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
        adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");

        var result = adSearch.FindOne();

        var employeeId = result.Properties["employeeID"][0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that. That's not what I asked. I want to know how I can get either a `UserPrincipal` object from a `SearchResultCollection` (the result of searching the Global Catalog using a `DirectorySearcher` object), or get access to all the attributes that are not replicated to the Global Catalog, like Employee ID.

Comment: You can't get the information from a DirectoryEntry? They would contain the same attributes.

Comment: But, once you find the user as a `DirectoryEntry` object, you should be able to search the Active Directory using a `PrincipalContext` to get the `UserPrincipal` object for that user. Isn't that right?

Comment: At this line: `var rootName = de.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString();`, I got a `COMException: Unknown error (0x8000500c)`.

Comment: I don't get the error if I use `GC://rootDSE` just like in your code. But, the `employeeId` is still not available. Also, I don't understand how I can connect to the Global Catalog this way, without providing a path.

Comment: The rootDomainNameingContext will give you your root domain to bind. You'll have to figure the root domain yourself. If you're on a domain joined machine, it's the suffix after your full machine name, so it would be something like `GC://corp.company.com`. Using this, you wouldn't need the `de` member in the example above, and would put the address in the `userBinding` member contructor. Hope that helps.

Comment: I do have the `GC://corp.company.com` path. But, again, the problem is that `employeeId` is not replicated to the Global Catalog.

Comment: Change to an LDAP query to connect to a local DC then.  `LDAP://corp.company.com` or `LDAP://domain.forest.company.com`

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked. I updated your answer. Also, `result.Properties["employeeID"]` returns an array, so you need to get the first item in the array.